# How to perform update in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update my record,but its not happening in my case and i am not sure about the case where it went rong,can any one suggest me help.Thanks

My mongoose code,

```
exports.updatestudent = function (req, res) {
var student = new Student(req.body);
var data = {};
var id = req.params;
var params = req.body;
var item = {
    'name': params.name,
    'rollnumber': params.rollnumber,
    'class': params.class,
    'city': params.city
};
Student.update({ _id: id },{ $set: item }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err');
    }
    if (result) {
        data = { status: 'success', error_code: 0, result: result, message: 'Article updated successfully' };
        res.json(data);
    }
});
```

};

my schema,

```
  var StudentSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  rollnumber: {
    type: String
  },
  class: {
    type: String
  },
   city: {
    type: String
  },
  status: {
    type: String
  },
  _id: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId
  }
});
/**
 * Hook a pre validate method to test the local password
 */
mongoose.model('student', StudentSchema, 'student');
```

my result in postman,
      {
      "status": "success",
      "error_code": 0,
      "result": {
        "ok": 0,
        "n": 0,
        "nModified": 0
      },
      "message": "Article updated successfully"
    }

I am trying to update my record,but its not happening in my case and i am not sure about the case where it went rong,can any one suggest me help.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are getting your `id` in `var id = req.params;`

> And I am sure you will not get your `id` like this

check your `req.params;` values  and give your correct id in the query

**Update**

```
var item = {};

if (params.name) {
  item.name = params.name;
}
if (params.rollnumber) {

  item.rollnumber = params.rollnumber
}


Student.update({
  _id: id
}, {
  $set: item
}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('err');
  }
  if (result) {
    data = {
      status: 'success',
      error_code: 0,
      result: result,
      message: 'Article updated successfully'
    };
    res.json(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: i cleared it by using     var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);console.log(id)

Comment: mean your id is coming in `req.params.id` not in `req.params` update your query and it should work

Comment: ok but if i give only name in body to update remaing fields are becoming null,how can i stop it

Comment: check your all field before query and put that data which comes and skip which is not available by `if` statement

Comment: see my update part in answer that way you can avoid null, you can find another way but it seems to easy to handle all things

Comment: k some times i may give name and class and some time class and city

Comment: You can check all the things like this

Answer (score 2):

It seems you forgot to specify the key.

Replace

```
var id = req.params;
```

By

```
var id = req.params.id;
```